# How to get chosen file from GtkFileChooserDialog?

Tags: c, gtk

I created a filechooser dialog in Glade. I placed OK and Cancel buttons in it. After that I set the clicked handler of the GtkButton to be open_clicked or whatever; also I have a button which displays the filechooser dialog. Its signal handler is `cb_show_filed`. Here is my code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
typedef struct _Data Data;
struct _Data
{
    GtkWidget *file;
};
G_MODULE_EXPORT void cb_show_filed(GtkButton *button, Data *data)
{
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(data->file));
    gtk_widget_hide(data->file);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *filechooserdialog1;
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "ui.glade", NULL);
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window1"));
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    filechooser =
        GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "filechooserdialog1"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, &data);
    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(builder));
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();
    return (0);
}
```

Now, how can I get path and filename from `filechooserdialog1`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`gtk_file_chooser_get_file()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#gtk-file-chooser-get-file) and friends:

```
GFile *chosen_file = gtk_file_chooser_get_file(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(filechooser));
```

Comment: gtk_file_chooser_get_file is for/from GTK3 but I using GTK2

Comment: It's also available in GTK 2: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#gtk-file-chooser-get-file